Copying value from excel file with long file name and pasting value into spreadsheetgear is removing formula in excel using c#
I'm using SpreadSheetgear 2023 in my project and I'm facing an issue while copying values from Excel to Spreadsheetgear.
Lets say Excel file as source and Spreadsheetgear as target, when I am copying value from source by pressing ctrl + C and pasting into target, the formula is removed from the source.
Note: this happens only when source file name length has more than 181 characters.
I've been looking online for awhile now and I cant seem to figure out any solution.
Here is my code what I am trying:
private void MyMethod(SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView workbookView)
{

  workbookView.GetLock();
  SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = workbookView.ActiveWorkbook;  
  SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
  SpreadsheetGear.IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;
  workbookView.PasteSpecial(SpreadsheetGear.PasteType.Values,          SpreadsheetGear.PasteOperation.None, false, false);
  workbookView.ReleaseLock();

}

I even tried by replacing workbookView.PasteSpecial() with workbookView.Paste(), but it didn't help.
